# Is there a word with a meaning roughly halfway between "adjust" and "fiddle with"?

Tags: meaning

"Adjust", "tweak", and "arrange" all seem deliberate and controlled, while "fiddle with" and "poke at" seem on the aimless side, at least to me. Is there a word somewhere between those extremes?

For example, when you're trying to get the correct key on your keychain using just one hand. It may take a few tries, but it's still too intentional and precise to qualify as "fumbling".

Comment: This is a judgement call ... I'll post as an answer if you think it close enough. **Finger** has at least a strong connotation of imprecision ‘Some of them were fiddling with the ball, while others fingered the handle of the bat, and others just sat with their feet against the gate before them with a tense look on their faces.’ / 
‘‘Your mom hates me,’ Jimmy said skeptically and fingered the door handle of my car, while remaining tense.’ [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/finger)] // 'She fingered her necklace absent-mindedly as she talked.' ...

Comment: [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/finger)] But of course, precision is a distinct possibility (To their surprise, he fingered the guitar expertly).

Comment: 'Struggle with'?

Comment: I would move "tweak" out of the *deliberate and controlled* column and nudge to halfway to the "aimless" column. Oh -- there's a word -- how about *nudge* ?